# Finding unique data for Bluetooth Low Energy connected HID device on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-registry, bluetooth

I am trying to read out any type of information that can tell me if a Bluetooth Low Energy HID device (mouse/keyboard) has been connected previously to a computer with Windows 8.1 (which has the BLE stack).

Under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\BTHLE` I can see when devices get connected and assigned an hardware ID. The problem is that this ID increases its value whenever the device pair is removed and repaired, in other words, this ID is not unique.
I have been trying to compare these data with what's under `...Enum\BTHLEDevice`, but I cannot figure out what that is not changing from time to time.

What registry values stays unique for a given device throughout the lifetime of the Windows installation? It may be helpful if anyone knows the answer to this question with regular Bluetooth devices as well.

Some directory structure for `\Enum\BTHLE\`:

> Dev_f3485b7b4df5
>
> > 8&34482aba&0&f3485b7b4df5
> >
> > > Device Parameters
> > >
> > > Properties

Some keys under 8&34482aba&0&f3485b7b4df5

ClassGUID = {e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}

HardwareID = BTHLE\Dev_f3485b7b4df5

Under Enum\BTHLEDevice five folders get created upon pairing:

> {00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_Dev_VID&021915_PID&0040_REV&0001_f3485b7b4df5
>
> > 9&166333ec&1&0001
>
> {00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_Dev_VID&021915_PID&0040_REV&0001_f3485b7b4df5
>
> > 9&166333ec&1&0008
>
> {0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_Dev_VID&021915_PID&0040_REV&0001_f3485b7b4df5
>
> > 9&166333ec&1&000C
>
> {0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_Dev_VID&021915_PID&0040_REV&0001_f3485b7b4df5
>
> > 9&166333ec&1&0013
>
> {00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_Dev_VID&021915_PID&0040_REV&0001_f3485b7b4df5
>
> > 9&166333ec&1&0017

Here the HardwareID keys look more like this:

```
BTHLEDevice\{00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_Dev_VID&021915_PID&0040_REV&0001
BTHLEDevice\{00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_Dev_VID&021915_PID&0040
BTHLEDevice\{00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_LOCALMFG&0048
```

Comment: BTLE works a little differently then normal BT.  The way devices are paired is simplified.  The key is basically static.  Can you provide more information about the data contained in this registry key?

Comment: @Ramhound I tried supplying you with a little more info. Hope it helps